# How to sync files between PC and USB

Tags: sync, file-sharing, dropbox, task-scheduler

I need to sync a file between my computer and a USB stick. The sync needs to happen in real time, as in when the right file changes sync to the left file and vice versa. I tried looking at Task Scheduler but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a trigger that detects a file change. I don't know if there is a way to incorporated Drop box and a batch file but Help would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) - I use it to Sync network drives with a local folder. I think there is an option for auto-detection of changed files.

Comment: It will detect any files and folders that have been changed, added, etc, but doesn't run constantly in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using Windows so I would suggest looking into its built-in Offline Files capabilities.

Check out [this comment](http://lifehacker.com/5893547/how-can-i-sync-my-files-without-having-to-store-them-online?comment=48094644#comments) to a related Lifehacker article that suggests using Windows' "Offline Files" feature to quickly sync multiple files between computers.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html).  It's dead simple to set up *bi*-directional syncing between two directories--local or remote.